# WSL2: Why am I unable to sudo?

Tags: sudo, path, windows-subsystem-for-linux

```
[username@MACHINE bin]$ sudo
sudo: Files/Microsoft: command not found
```

I can `sudo` just fine as root.  I thought this might be due to spaces introduced into `PATH` by WSL, but for both the root and non-root accounts, neither enclosing all paths in quotes nor escaping the spaces fixes this problem.

**EDIT:** This is apparently due to devtoolset-7 prepending my `PATH` with `/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin`, which includes a `sudo` executable.  I would rather not have to type `/bin/sudo` every time I wish to invoke superuser access; by what means may I make `/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/sudo` usable?

Comment: looks like a [known issue](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1319936) that is being actively **ignored** - does your login shell have `alias`? you could do `alias sudo='/usr/bin/sudo'` in your shells *rc* file - wonder if that would break some *devtoolset-7* functionality though

Comment: Thanks for heads-up, Bravo.  I thought of just `alias`ing `sudo`, but yeah, I don't know what effect that would have on devtoolset.  I'm just typing the full path to `/bin/sudo`, for now.

Comment: sorry, yeah, it's `/bin/sudo` in some distros :p - you could alias `sud` instead - though any scripts that use `sudo` would probably still have the issue - just re-read the link I gave you, and it seems that the issue was *closed with a
resolution of ERRATA* (whatever that means) - `Fix: 
More sudo options are correctly parsed.

Result: 
The sudo wrapper works more like the normal /usr/bin/sudo.` - seems it should be working

Comment: It was apparently fixed in devtoolset-9, according to the page.  I upgraded to devtoolset-10, and the problem persists.  :P  I'm just going to stick with `/bin/sudo`.